# How to show text on ImageButton on mouse over by css

Tags: asp.net

I have an image button inside the div. I am increasing the image size and z-index on the hover on div. but I want to add some text over the image button when the hover is calling. how can I do ?

my css:

```
.HoverImageClass input[type=image]:hover
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10000;
    height: 274px;
    width: 226px;
    margin-top: -67px;
    margin-left: -14px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    background-color: #F7F6EB;
}
```

my html:

```
<div id="divImageDisplay" class="HoverImageClass" runat="server">


<asp:ImageButton runat="server" CssClass="course_img" ID="imgbtnCourse" AlternateText='<%#Eval("LevelName") %>' ToolTip='<%#Eval("LevelName") %>' ImageUrl='<%#Eval("CourseImagePath") %>' CausesValidation="False" CommandName="AddToCart" CommandArgument='<%# String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}",Eval("ID"),Eval("LevelID"),Eval("CurrencyWithValue"),Eval("CourseImagePath"),Eval("CategoryID"),Eval("MRP"))  %>'></asp:ImageButton>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you run this code, view the source and give us the generated HTML of that image button? I well know the real markup we can help you better.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you do the text on the button via normal HTML, one possible method would to on the main CSS class make the " color:"" " the same as that of the background, and then on the :hover class, you could change it to a different color that would be readable/eligible. Or possibly you could even set the font size to something really tiny on the original, then bump it up a size on the :hover!

Hope it helps!

Comment: That won't be a good idea.. if you want to hide it with CSS then use display:none and don't just give it a color you don't know if the image will change or what's it's texture

Comment: but it is a imagebutton , how can i keep one control within image button?.